# Extracting value from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary is like this:

```
query =  {'fowl': [{'cateogry': 'Space'}, {'cateogry': 'Movie'}, {'cateogry': 'six'}], u'Year of the Monkey': {'score': 40, 'match': [{'category': u'Movie'}, {'category': 'heaven'}, {'category': 'released'}]}}
```

`fowl` and `Year of the Monkey` are two entities in this. I am trying to extract all `category` values for both entities separately with no luck.

None of these work:

```
query[0] # I was expecting values for fowl
query[0]['category'] # I was expecting all category for fowl but seems wrong
query[0]['category'][0] # category space for fowl
```

what is the correct approach?

Comment: Instead of positions, use keys.

Comment: also `'cateogry'` is a mis-spelling, fix it now before all your code depends on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `query` dictionary is rather funky, for one, `'fowl'` and `'Year of the Monkey'` values are not structured the same, so you cannot aply the same data access patterns, or categories being misspelled as `'cateogry'`. If you can, you may be better off fixing that before trying to process it further.

As for extracting the `'fowl'` data:

```
>>> query =  {'fowl': [{'cateogry': 'Space'}, {'cateogry': 'Movie'}, {'cateogry': 'six'}], u'Year of the Monkey': {'score': 40, 'match': [{'category': u'Movie'}, {'category': 'heaven'}, {'category': 'released'}]}}

>>> query['fowl'] # 'fowl'
[{'cateogry': 'Space'}, {'cateogry': 'Movie'}, {'cateogry': 'six'}]

>>> [d['cateogry'] for d in query['fowl']] # 'fowl' categories
['Space', 'Movie', 'six']

>>> [d['cateogry'] for d in query['fowl']][0] # 'fowl' 'Space' category
'Space'
```

Comment: thanks, `print query['Year of the Monkey']['match']` gives category for second entity. Her name of entities changes every time. Is there any way to iterate through all entities and get there categories?

Answer (score 1):

`query` is a dictionary not a list, so do `query['fowl']` instead

Comment: thanks, `print query['Year of the Monkey']['match']` gives category for second entity. Her name of entities changes every time. Is there any way to iterate through all entities and get there categories?

Answer (score 1):

`query['Year of the Monkey']['match'][0]['category']` you need to iterate